# unable to locate package libc while install nagios

Tags: glibc

i want to install Nagios so, tried to install the nagios on local station and i get these error about unable to locate package libc.
i tried to find out what missing and didn't find yet, also tried some addons, and nothing worked out yet, 
[picture describe the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJsF6.jpg)
thank you

Comment: Do you try `sudo apt install libc6`?

Comment: yes, these works, thank you,
can you explain please ?